# Postgres reset password in PostgreSQL server 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I have more than 20 databases in my PostgreSQL 8.4 server. Someone did something wrong to my Postgres and it is not opening anymore. It gives the following error:

```
error connecting to the server fatal role postgres is not permitted to log in
```

I did lot to recover it but it still not working. I have PostgreSQL server 8.4 in windows XP.

`pg_hba.conf` file configuration is:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
#local   all   postgres                         ident sameuser
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
#host    all         postgres trust 
#host    all         all         192.168.44.12/32      trust
#host    all         all         192.168.44.103/32     trust
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all         all         192.168.44.18/32      trust
# host   all     all     ::1/128     md5
```

I suspect that the problem is here because someone modified the `ROLE` of Postgres user in `NOT LOG IN`...

Comment: is the database on the same machine you are connecting from?

Comment: yes database is in the same machine i connecting...

Comment: did you create any other users than the default `postgres` user?

Comment: yes i created but i didn't remember the username.

Comment: your pg_hba.conf allows all users to connect; do you have a `createuser.exe` program hanging around with your Postgres binaries?

Comment: yaa I have createuser.exe. what to do now? I have to create a new user ? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly try single user mode. Stop postgres, then run it from the command line:

```
postgres --single -D path/to/your/postgres/directory
```

Then:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH LOGIN
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to terminate the session.

That should allow the `postgres` user to log into the server once again.

Comment: Same error is coming postgres is not permited to log in while creating new user through createuser.exe

Comment: Added single user mode comment.

Comment: I got an error Postgres is not recognized as the internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: the command i given in the cmd is that.. postgres --single -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\postgres.exe

Comment: Thanks lot @ cfeduke  my problem is solved........... may god bless you always.....