# postgresql data directory not connecting

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I am using windows 8.
My Postgres was Correct.
I just took the data directory from `C:/postgresql/8.3/`
Now database was connected through command prompt.
When I was trying to connect using pgadmin, it's saying

```
FATEL: error
An error has occured:
Error connecting to sthe server: FATAL: role "postgres" is not permitted to log in
```

I changed the required things in pg_hba.conf (trust) and postgresql.conf (connection *) (port 5433)

But, still I was unable to connect the database.

How to give the permissions to postgres role.
when am trying to give the permissions through cmd also it's giving same error.

I was tried in so many ways
but, still I didn't get the database.

Comment: Are you using the PostgreSQL 8.3 version because you cannot take a data directory from different version from the one you're currently using. Is it an imported data directory or fresh install - has there been any changes to the database login roles? _"Now database was connected through command prompt"_ - do you mean you can connect to the database via `psql`?

Comment: Question seems like it would be more suitable for serverfault

Comment: Yes the data directly and currently installed postgres versions both are same (8.3) and I didn't connected to database through psql........ I just enable the database using cmd.........
like if We have data directory in C:/postgres/8.3/sample/data then we can enable database which is available in data directory
with the help of cmd,the command is
C:/***/8.3/bin>postgres.exe -D <data dir path> -p5433
5433 is changed port .that have to be changed in data directory postgresql.conf  file

Comment: then it will create .pid file in data directory
now we can conform that the database was enabled successfully
then we can connect to that port through psql or pgadmin III

When I tried to connect the database in this way using current (fresh Installed data) data directory it's successfully connected. but when i was trying to connect old data (currepted database data dir) directory it's saying role postgres is not permitted to log in
What should i do? please give me suggessions

Comment: Or else
I just replace the Old data directory in fresh installed postgres/8.3 folder
Then also it's giving same error

Just help me to connect my database
versions are same and modify hba-conf(trust) and postgresql.conf file also

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have accidentally revoked the `LOGIN` and `SUPERUSER` rights from the `postgres` user. Perhaps you created a superuser with a different name instead? Log in as that user if you did.

If not, and you can't get access as user `postgres`, you will need to start the database engine up in *single-user mode* and manually `GRANT` the `SUPERUSER` right to `postgres` again. This is much the same process as is required when recovering from a dropped (deleted) superuser account.

See related:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44586/7788
- [Postgres reset password in PostgreSQL server 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15170658/398670)

BTW, 8.3 is a very old and unsupported version. Plan your upgrade promptly.

If there's no data in PostgreSQL that you care about, the easiest thing to do will be:

- Uninstall PostgreSQL 8.3;
- Delete `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3` (permanently and unrecoverably destroying all data in your PostgreSQL databases); and
- Install a current PostgreSQL version